# Stroke with text

Tags: android, android-custom-drawable

I was wondering that is it possible to create a custom drawable with stroke as border and this stroke contains text and for my ths question see the following image that I have created on Paint.
[image]

I have created a Linear Layout with stroke and a text 'Hello World' is on the stroke, so the question once again is that is it possible to  create this type of stroke.

Comment: is the log in and sign up text a button?

Comment: use the new `MaterialCardView` it has two stroke attributes :
`app:strokeWidth="(your width)"` and `app:strokeColor="(your color)"`
https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/

Comment: for the hello world textview I suggest you use constratintlayout and constraint the top and bottom of the tv to the top of the materialcardview and give some marginStart to the tv and aslo some elevation, it will look exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected design can be achieved by the following code I just did and checked:

First use a custom background in `drawable`: *bg_gray_rectangle_rounded_corners.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#00B6625D"/>

</shape>
```

then in your main `xml` file copy and paste this `snippet`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_rectangle_rounded_corners"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_rectangle_rounded_corners"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_rectangle_rounded_corners"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#636262"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the output**

[image: output]

Have a good day. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Welcome. If it works and helps you, please make it as the correct answer.